# add message to python logging no matter which log level

Tags: python, logging

i have another python problem related to logging. I want to have a message logged to my log file no matter which log level i'm using. For example i always want to print the time when the program was last executed and also the git version hash of the script.

Is there a way to log something to the log file no matter what log level is set?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `logging.info('your msg goes here')`

Comment: @mad_ `info` level messages won't get logged if the log level is set to `warn` or `error`.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood log levels. A message will be logged if it is at the same *or higher* level as the log level of the handler. If you always want something to be logged, log it at the highest level.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Indeed i could use the CRITICAL log level but i don't want to missuse these level calls. i thought there must be a simpler way to log something everytime. Like: `logging.log("test")` or something which despite the log level alsways prints and doesn't shows up as CRITICAL or ERROR.

Comment: But again I think your approach is wrong. These are by definition INFO messages; if your handler has been configured at a higher level, that's because it doesn't want those messages. It's not (and shouldn't be) up to the code that emits the message to override that setting.

Comment: On the other hand, it's up to you what level you want your logger to log at at any given time. If you want to temporarily allow lower-priority messages, there's nothing stopping you from changing the log level, logging the lower-priority messages, and then changing the log level back.